# C# - XML read from https link + popup username/pw box

Tags: c#, xml, https

Greetings

I'm trying to get an xml file from a website which requires me to fill in a username and API key.

Example:

```
public void GetTournaments(string userName, string apiKey, string tournamentName)
{
 string getXMLAdress = "https://" + userName + ":" + apiKey + "@challonge.com/api/tournaments/" + tournamentName + "/participants.xml";
 XmlDocument tournamentsXML = new XmlDocument();
 tournamentsXML.Load(getXMLAdress);
}
```

The API on the website shows that you only need this information.. however it always returns a  401 that I have no access. Now I noticed when I put this in my browser I still had to fill in my Username and password as well. When using the above URL it shows a popup box where you can fill in your username/password.

I could always let users download the files themselves but that would be kind of an hassle. So I'm wondering if there is an alternative way or if I can fill in the popup box through C#.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the userName/apiKey alphanumeric?

Comment: I'm fairly certain both are yes since the Username depends on what the user will fill in :). The API-key definitely is and I'm guessing some users will have a username with a number in it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the credentials through a WebClient and use it to load the required XML file from the Web Server.

```
    public static void GetFileWithCredentials(string userName, string password, string url)
    {

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            string xml = wc.DownloadString(url);

            XmlDocument tournamentsXML = new XmlDocument();
            tournamentsXML.LoadXml(xml);
        }

    }
```

If the userName contains domain information, do pass it separately in the overloaded constructor of `NetworkCredential(string userName, string password, string domain)`

Hope that helps!